# Index Error when i run multiple process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

This script throws index error

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool 
import re
import urllib2 

def btl_test(url):                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    page1 =  (re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)<\/title>',page)[0])
    return page1

url = ["http://google.com","http://example.com","http://yahoo.com","http://linkedin.com","http://facebook.com","http://orkut.com","http://oosing.com","http://pinterets.com"]

nprocs = 100 # nprocs is the number of processes to run
ParsePool = Pool(nprocs)
ParsedURLS = ParsePool.map(btl_test,url)
print ParsedURLS
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multithread1.py", line 15, in <module>
    ParsedURLS = ParsePool.map(btl_test,url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Above is error message

Where is the problem occured and what is the solution?

Comment: You should also post the traceback and the error message

Comment: Maybe you can diagnose more easily but first running a single-process script: `for u in url: btl_test(u)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is chance that a `url does not have title tag`

So convert from this to

```
def btl_test(url):                                                                                                             
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    page1 =  (re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)<\/title>',page)[0])
    return page1
```

This

```
def btl_test(url):                                                               
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    page1 =  re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)<\/title>',page)
    return (page1[0]) if len(page1)>0 else "None"
```